# Does PIXE only measure external composition?

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, x-rays

When performing X-ray spectroscopy, say with PIXE, do atoms inside the metal have vacancies induced or only the outer layer?

For example, a quarter has a shell of 75% copper and 25% nickel, but a bulk composition of 8.33% nickel and 91.67% copper. If I perform X-ray spectroscopy, would I be measuring the shell composition or the bulk composition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical Particle-Induced X-ray Emission (PIXE) uses an incident proton or alpha particle of a few MeV. Electronic stopping of this particle transfers energy to electrons in the sample, exciting them up from valence states. Electrons relaxing back down into those empty states release the characteristic x-rays.

So, the first question is how deep in does a ~1MeV proton or alpha go? Roughly speaking this is on the order of 1 to a few (maybe 10) microns, depending of course on just what the substrate is. So that is an indication of the maximum depth that you might be able to produce an x-ray.

Then, will the x-ray actually get out? Generally speaking, from a few microns the answer is yes. So, it is the range of the incident particle that determines the depth of the probe. And, it is the near-surface region.